# PyDoctor doesn't create documentation for one module

Tags: python

I set pydoctor loose on my source code:

```
pydoctor *.py
```

and the auto-generated code seems nice, except for one of my modules  just has a page saying "engine : module documentation - Undocumented". The module itself has a docstring as well as the class in it and several methods in it. It doesn't even list the methods or classes in engine.py. The only thing that stands out about engine.py other than sheer size is the number of modules it imports, but I don't see why that should be a problem.

```
import pygame, pygame.event, pygame.image, pygame.display
import EntityTypes, threading, main
import sys, time, events, collision, player, traceback
from functools import wraps
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

somehow I see this a very long time after the question is asked... I can't help without seeing the module though.  The only thing I can think of is that engine.py's docstring isn't being recognized as such for some reason.